# How to store multiple JSON values in to single row of database?

Tags: mysql, json

I get an input in JSON format, and that value should be stored in MySQL database. I want to store more than 1 image URL in a single row. Is it possible, and how?

Below is the input in JSON format. I want to store multiple image data in single row?

```
{
    "session_id": "192urjh91f",
    "description": "description of the post",
    "location": "12.00847,-71.297489",
    "place_id": "917439",
    "images": [
        "url1",
        "url2",
        "url3"
    ],
    "audio": "audio url",
    "tags": [
        "1234",
        "31332",
        "12412"
    ],
    "people": [
        "user_id",
        "user_id1",
        "user_id2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: It is always recommended that the values in a column should be atomic. which means a column should contain single value for an record. If you want you can store the url into separate table.

Answer (score 0):

The clean way to store this sort of data in a relational database involves making one table for all the scalar (string or numeric) members of your object and an additional table for each array-valued member. You have three arrays (`images`, `tags`, and `people`), which means you'll need to create four tables with the following columns:

- `posts (post_id PRIMARY KEY, session_id, description, latitude, longitude, place_id, audio_uri)`
- `post_images (post_id, uri, PRIMARY KEY (post_id, uri))`
- `post_tags (post_id, tag_id, PRIMARY KEY (post_id, tag_id))`
- `post_people (post_id, user_id, PRIMARY KEY (post_id, user_id))`

(Translating these into actual `CREATE TABLE` statements is left as an exercise for someone who knows the acceptable values for each member.)

When you add a post, you add one row for the post itself, which should get its `post_id` through the `AUTO_INCREMENT` mechanism. Then take this `post_id` and use it to insert a row for each image, a row for each tag, and a row for each user.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there are always going to be three images the you could create three columns image1..3. If # of images is at runtime, then it is always better to have a separate table for images. If you have restrictions of the tables design then you can store into a single column with some delimiter.